# 'gcloud init' command returns "Permission denied"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I've installed Google Cloud SDK on my laptop.  The `gcloud` command is available/accessible via `git bash` from any subdirectory. However, the `gcloud init` command returns the following error:

> /c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud:
>   line 191: /c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python:
>   Permission denied /c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud
>   SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: line 191:
>   /c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission
>   denied

Any idea what the issue might be or how to debug it?

Comment: Seems that gcloud requires python to be installed and it's invoking python when you run the "init" command.  What happens if you run just "python" the same command shell that you're launching gcloud?  If it goes into a python shell, type quit() to exit.  I'm trying to see if python is installed properly.

Comment: Interesting - running "python" returns: "bash: /c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission denied".  What do you recommend as next steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, so your shell is `bash`?  And you're on Windows apparently, so try using a cmd shell (at the start menu, hunt for `cmd` and run it).  See if you can run `python` from there.  If that works, then running `gcloud`should probably work too.

If that doesn't work, then you've probably got `python` installed improperly somehow.  If you didn't install it, maybe something else installed it for you as part of a package.  You should probably uninstall and reinstall it (https://www.python.org/downloads/).  Also check if `gcloud` requires any specific version of `python` first.

Comment: Interesting - I got the same error when running "gcloud init" from the command prompt.  BUT running the python command opened up a dialog for the Microsoft Store with Python for download.  so I downloaded and installed python this way and now running "gcloud init" from the *command prompt* (not git bash) is successful.  not sure if I've ever encountered a command like that before which fails from git bash but succeeds from command prompt.  anyways - issue solved - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Include location of python in your path.

If it looks for some other name of python e.g. python3, include soft link to python

prompt> ln -s python python3